# I want to retrieve associated object like a nested array in node js

Tags: node.js, node-orm2

How can I send course object with section and section instance data as single json response

```
Section.hasOne('course', db.models.courses, {reverse: 'section'});

Section_Instance.hasOne('course', db.models.courses, {reverse: 'section_instance'});
Section_Instance.hasOne('section', db.models.sections, {reverse: 'section_instance'});
```

Comment: Please work on making your question clear so we can tell what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the async.js library. For your problem, use async.parallel:

> npm install --save async

```
var async = require("async");
async.parallel({
course: function (callback) {
// course query here
callback(null, results_from_coursequery); // null is error - you can also assign the error variable from query.
},
section: function (callback) {
// course query here
callback(null, results_from_sectionquery); // null is error - you can also assign the error variable from query.
}
},
function(err,results) {
if(err) {res.json(err);}
else {res.send(results);} // results is now an object similar to: {course: [object], section: [object]}
});
```

Comment: sorry sir under course object i want section object like nested array ..for example........                                                                                            var pets = new Array ( );
pets[0] = new Array ( "Sheba", 13, "cat" )                     ;...............................like Tree

Comment: Sir i want to bundle the json response as a tree

Comment: You can build your object any way you like, just create the object like you want, and send that in the callback function.

Comment: It's a bit hard when I don't know neither your code, your goal or your collection, but basically you would: a) perform your query b) inside your promise resolving, build out the tree you want to return c) callback(null,tree); d) at the very end (inside err,results functions), you can create your tree any way you'd like before returning them.